# Converting a UTC date string to another timezone maintaining the same format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone

I'd like to convert a UTC date string into the current users timezone and maintain the format of the date string.

For example, I have this code which works:

```
var data = '2017-04-24 12:06:37';
var date = new Date(data+' UTC');

console.log(date.toString()); // logs "Mon Apr 24 2017 08:06:37 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

How do I get this to output the new date string in the exact same format dynamically?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "dynamically"? Do you mean that the input format could vary and you want the output format to be whatever the input format happens to be?  If so, what are all the possible input formats you might handle? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah I just ended up using moment.js.

Comment: You should either post your solution as an answer, or delete your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I used with momentjs:

`moment.utc(value).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to **add** `UTC` to the string **before you convert** it to a date.

To convert any date to a UTC string, you can use

```
 var UTCstring = (new Date()).toUTCString();
```

See my snippet. It compares the five different methods.

```js
var date = new Date('2017-04-24 12:06:37 PM UTC');
var local = date.toString();
var utc = date.toUTCString();
var iso = date.toISOString();
var dateString = date.toDateString();
console.log(date);
console.log(local);
console.log(utc);
console.log(iso);
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, and the part you put in bold, the OP is already doing.

Comment: Because it's not clear what the OP mean in general, I showed him some ways on how to format time to string

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  But in general, if you're not sure what the OP meant, you should ask for clarification in comments.  The other acceptable approach is to answer with a presumption, as in, "If you meant foo, then the answer is ...", but that typically won't earn you upvotes unless the OP confirms their intention.  Either way, answering with ancillary information on the subject isn't a good approach, especially with information easily found via Google search, and already prevalent on other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Remember, the goal of StackOverflow is not just to answer a single person's question, but to provide a compendium of question/answer pairs that are useful to the entire community.  If the answer doesn't fit the question, it becomes noise.